# PHP IDE with autolinkage of files based on pattern?

Tags: php, windows, macos, ide

I have a structure of php files related with each other in a predictable way. I'm using a modified version of the MVC pattern used in asp.net. Since I'm frequently switching between files I find that I'm opening too many tabs for them to be useful.

Most of the files are classes calling and instancing each other so code-links like css-files included by html in dreamweaver, for example, doesn't work.

I still want tabs as well so I can switch between groups of these related files.

`Source Code`, `user_registration.php` and `users_wider.css` are the links here.
The links i talked about are just below this text. 
[image]

Is there a way in any free or low-cost IDE to get automatically updating links as described to all the related files? I'm using Windows and Mac. One IDE for both OS:es would be nice but one is better than none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way of doing this in Dreamweaver CS5 (by accident). This is probably a bug.
If you comment away a php require or include dreamweaver still links those files.

[image]

So by adding a few lines of comments anywhere in the document (i prefer the top) you can "link" any files the same way Dreamweaver links css and js that's added in html.

Works on both mac 10.6 and windows 7. Haven't tested any other version yet.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains's PhpStorm might be a good option. http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

I haven't used this specific IDE before, but I have used ReSharper and IntelliJ, two other products of theirs. They make quality stuff. It's not free, but there's a trial so you can see if it will fit what you need before you buy.